# Getty service does not start

Tags: centos7, systemd

I have run into trouble with booting to `multi-user.target` on one of my Centos 7 servers. At first I noticed that running the `runlevel` command does returns an "unknown" level.

```
# runlevel
unknown
```

I suspected that it might be caused by the inactive `multi-user.target`, which is the default target.

```
# systemctl status multi-user.target
multi-user.target - Multi-User System
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

# systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
```

When I tried to start it manually, the command just hung and nothing happened. I noticed that the `getty.target`, `multi-user.target` depends on, is also down and there is a pending `start` job.

```
# systemctl -t target
UNIT                  LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB    JOB   DESCRIPTION
basic.target          loaded active   active       Basic System
cryptsetup.target     loaded active   active       Encrypted Volumes
getty.target          loaded inactive dead   start Login Prompts
local-fs-pre.target   loaded active   active       Local File Systems (Pre)
local-fs.target       loaded active   active       Local File Systems
multi-user.target     loaded inactive dead   start Multi-User System
network-online.target loaded active   active       Network is Online
network-pre.target    loaded active   active       Network (Pre)
network.target        loaded active   active       Network
paths.target          loaded active   active       Paths
remote-fs-pre.target  loaded active   active       Remote File Systems (Pre)
remote-fs.target      loaded active   active       Remote File Systems
slices.target         loaded active   active       Slices
sockets.target        loaded active   active       Sockets
spice-vdagentd.target loaded active   active       Agent daemon for Spice guests
swap.target           loaded active   active       Swap
sysinit.target        loaded active   active       System Initialization
timers.target         loaded active   active       Timers
```

Starting `getty.target`/`getty@tty1.service` had the same effect - command just hung. Unfortunatelly, I could not find any reason for this behaviour using the `journalctl`.

Just as I was writing the last paragraph, I thought of stopping the pending start job on `getty.target` and starting it over. **That actually solved my main problem as stopping the pending job allowed `multi-user.target` to activate**.

```
systemctl --job-mode=replace stop getty.target
```

That still does not explain why the `getty.target` refuses to start. Do any of you have an idea why this might be happening or is there some other log I can look into?

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker ran into a issue with getty/multi-user systemd targets not starting. When he connected to the console there was a prompt that he had to acknowledge/answer a question so that things could proceed past which allowed for getty/multi-user to start.

This is a screenshot from the prompt:

[image: ss of console]

This issue is referenced here as well: [“License not accepted” when CentOS 7 initiate](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49229). The EULA that you need to agree to can be automatically accepted via kickstart as described here - [kickstart with eula - finish configuration](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55874).

Comment: I believe this is provided by the `firstboot` package, which can be omitted from the installation if desired.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - true. It's unclear to me if omitting that will do it. It's also confusing b/c there's 3 RPMs that seem to be involved here - firstboot, initial-setup, and initial-setup-gui. It's somewhat discussed here - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax (under the firstboot section).